# Selecting a range by mouse and setting parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do the following with Excel 2010 VBA:

1. set a toggle button on a form.
2. move to the worksheet
3. use the mouse to select groups (range) of cells
4. set a cell parameter (background colour) to the back colour of the toggle button
   .
   .
   .
   continue select cells or deselect the toggle button.

What I have so far is this but I get a global range error on the line setting the colour:

```
Public Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim ActRange As Range
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
Dim bgndColour As Variant

  bgndColour = ToggleButton1.BackColor

  Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
  Set ActRange = Selection
  ActSheet.Select
  ActRange.Select
  Range(ActRange).Interior.Color = bgndColour

End Sub
```

Comment: Why use a toggle button for this and not the refedit control?

Comment: Because I have a number of toggle buttons that will each, eventually, perform different actions on the cells. and I want the buttons to be configurable.

Comment: I dont like to add inecesary lines, I see you can resume your code in Selection.Interior.Color = bgndColour, if that is not working what is wrong is your bgndcolour variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActRange` is already a range. No need to use the `Range()` object

Try this

```
ActRange.Interior.Color = bgndColour
```

Your code can be reduced to

```
Public Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Selection.Interior.Color = ToggleButton1.BackColor
End Sub
```

Comment: Preselecting the range will not work for me as I want to set the button state and all the time it is set be free to select cells for marking; however, I realise now that this is in the 'click' action so will have to alter this.

I will try to optimise after I understand how it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont like to add inecesary lines, I see you can resume your code in

```
Selection.Interior.Color = bgndColour
```

if that is not working what is wrong is your bgndcolour variable